# How to find the last paragraph element?

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of several paragraph tags. Each is without any attributes e.g.

```
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
```

My goal is to find the last opening `<p>` tag – no matter if I only have a single paragraph or ten. I always want the last paragraph opening tag.

With

```
/<p>/
```

I get the first paragraph tag. I thought `$` inverts the search direction from left-to-right to right-to-left. So basically

```
/<p>$/
```

should return the opening paragraph tag for the third paragraph from my example above; but the regex finds nothing at all.

So how to best target the last paragraph?

Comment: obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: To be clear, you want **1)** the last paragraph opening tag or **2)** *the last paragraph element, beginning with its opening tag*?  The difference is important, but **1)** seems to make little sense because the last opening paragraph tag...is of course *no different than any preceding opening paragraph tag* in this case (unless you are interested in its index within the input string).

Comment: @j0e3gan i want case 1). I perform a `preg_replace` within a wordpress function. I want to apply a class to the very last opening `p` tag and add a padding after. The function targets only fields of the ACF plugin using wrapping `p` tags, which are wyiwyg fields only. I could have gone with a wrapping div for the fields and use :last-child in the CSS but i am not a fan of extending the html markup. That way i use the function only on a certain page and only on the wysiwyg fields and the user is able to enter extra paragraphs afterwards and the class is still applied to each last `p` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` does not change the search direction, it simply matches at the end of the text, that's all.

If you want to find the last `<p>`, you have to use a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert there aren't any more occurences of `<p>`:

```
(?s)<p>(?!.*<p>)
```

Answer (score 3):

use this pattern

```
[\s\S]*\K(<p>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/172)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
preg_match_all('#<p>.*</p>#',$string,$results);
$last_paragraph = array_pop($results[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
(<p>)([^<]*)<\/p>$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GtobgGUppv9TO21n)

Here is a PHP demo to test the pattern with the sample input you provided...

```
<?php 

$test = <<<TEST
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
TEST;

preg_match('/<p>([^<]*)<\/p>$/', $test, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

?>
```

..., which outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "<p>Third paragraph</p>"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "<p>"
  [2]=>
  string(15) "Third paragraph"
}
```

You can [run the PHP demo on Ideone](http://ideone.com/fpAVdZ) too.

As you can see, the pattern matches the last paragraph element.  I just added parentheses for capture groups to give you the option of getting the last paragraph element itself *or* its opening tag *or* its text.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = <<<MYFILE
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
MYFILE;
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/.*?(<p>(.*)<\/p>)$/';
preg_match($pattern,$str,$matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

A [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) Method with XPath

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<p>First paragraph</p><p>Second paragraph</p><p>Third paragraph</p>");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
if($elements = $xpath->query("//p[last()]"))
{
  echo $elements->item(0)->nodeName; // p
  echo $elements->item(0)->nodeValue; // Third paragraph
}
```

If you had a more complex HTML structure you would have to start getting explicit with your XPath Query however.